# Cronjob: Deleting the oldest file with at least 50GB while keeping 2 files in the directory

Tags: backup, cron, find

I have a backup script running that creates a ~300GB backup file to a backup folder daily. In that backup folder are some files that are smaller (less than 50GB) as well.

Using a cronjob I want to to keep the 2 most recent files that are larger than 50GB while ignoring the smaller files. Deleting the oldest file while having at least 2 files in the directory

So far I tried this:

```
find . -type f -size +50G -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort  | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs rm -f
```

This sorts the files that are bigger than 50GB in a list and deletes the oldest file.

I can't figure out how to make sure that it keeps at least 2 files with at least 50GB. In my imagination I should count the amount of files that are bigger than 50GB sort them by date and deletes the oldest? Is there anything I'm missing? Should I rather delete all but the youngest 2 files somehow?

Any tips/hints are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: have you thought of using the `! -newer <file>` (i.e. not newer) and pass in the oldest file you want to keep?

Comment: not yet, I will have a look at -newer.

Comment: as far as I understand the command this would also delete files although there are less than 2 files correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you almost make it (line splited for readability)

```
find . -type f -size +50G -printf '%T+ %p\n' |
  sort -r |
  awk 'NR>2 {print $2}' |
  xargs rm -f
```

where

- `sort -r` will list newest file first
- `NR>2` will select line starting from 3th
- `{print $2}` will print filename (provided filename has no space, tab or newline)

Comment: thank you, now that I see it it totally make sense!

Answer (score 0):

untested on my machine, as I don't have large files, or file I want deleting ... YMMV

I'm excluding the `basename $keepfile` in the second find statement, in the hopes that your files are uniquely named.

if they're not uniquely named, you'll probably want to replace `head -n 2 | tail -1` with `head -3 | tail -1` ... but that will always delete the oldest file.

If this system is for log rotation, you might be better off looking at syslog.conf, and adding in these files for automatic rotation and cleanup.

```
keepfile=`find . -type f -size +50G -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -n 2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'`

find . -type f -size +50G ! -newer $keepfile ! -name `basename $keepfile` -exec rm {} \; -print
```